# I want to shorten this method, can you help me?

Tags: java

I want to write this method in a shorter way. Do you have any ideas? I didn´t get something which runs...

```
public static AudioFile getInstance(String pathname) {
    String ending = null;
    int auxvar = pathname.lastIndexOf('.');

    if (auxvar<0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unknown suffix for AudioFile: \""+ pathname + "\"");
    }else {
        ending = pathname.substring(auxvar+1);
        ending = ending.toLowerCase();
        if (ending.equalsIgnoreCase("wav")) {
            return new WavFile(pathname);
        }else if (ending.equalsIgnoreCase("mp3") || ending.equalsIgnoreCase("ogg")) {
            return new TaggedFile(pathname);
        }else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unknown suffix for AudioFile: \" "+ pathname + "\" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you did not specify, what to return when `if condition` fails, i guess your code does not compile

Comment: `public static AudioFile getInstance(String p) { return null; }` -- You're welcome.

Comment: Why do you think this code needs shortening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you want that code, but shorter:

```
public static AudioFile getInstance(String path) {
    String pathc = path.toLowerCase();
    if (pathc.endsWith(".wav")) return new WavFile(path);
    if (pathc.endsWith("mp3") || pathc.endsWith(".ogg")) return new TaggedFile(path);
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown suffix for AudioFile: \""+ path + "\"");
}
```

Does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Monad-style solution with regex:

```
final static Pattern audioFilePattern = Pattern.compile(".*\\.(\\w+)");

public static AudioFile getInstance(String path) {
    return Optional.of(path)
        .map(audioFilePattern::matcher).filter(Matcher::matches)
        .map(m -> m.group(1).toLowerCase())
        .filter(s -> Stream.of("wav", "mp3", "ogg").anyMatch(s::equals))
        .map(s -> "wav".equals(s) ? new WavFile(path) : new TaggedFile(path))
        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown suffix for AudioFile: \"" + path + "\""));
}
```

Comment: I guess it serves as a fine example of why all this new lambda code is usually harder to follow (more code and more implicit paths the code could take), less efficient (it'll be slower), and less flexible (the lambdas are not control flow, mutable local variable, or checked exception transparent). Lambdas are useful. But use the right tool and all that. This isn't the kind of code where it ought to be used.